# Ignore an app-directory subfolder when using expo-router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm using expo-router for my react native app. I'm using the following type of file structure

```
app/
├── index.tsx
└── components/
    └── header.tsx
```

The problem is, expo-router then generates a screen at the route `components/header` which makes sense given the default behavior of expo-router, but is undesirable since header is meant only as a component for index.tsx and not as a screen itself.

Is there a way to prevent a folder in the app directory from being turned into routes? E.g. prefix it with `_` or something like that?

A simple solution would be to make a separate folder called components outside of the app directory, but this quickly becomes messy as the app grows. It is simpler to maintain if I can keep my components directories in the same folder at the screen they are used in.

Comment: So far, the best solution I have found is to not export a default component in the files in the `components` directory. This is not my typical approach but it is at least a solution.

Comment: Update: the solution I commented above does not work once you build the app. All of the components get made into screens that give the error: "Missing default export".

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a new components folder in the root. There you should place each page components you want to create and use later in app/ pages. This keeps the code cleaner too.